# How can I get the query to reference the `a.STRUCT_DOC_id` of the `where` clause below it?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I get the error

> "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 01427. 00000
>   - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

because the case statement  below returns two records.  It would NOT return two records if it could reference the same `a.STRUCT_DOC_id` from the `where` clause that is part of the larger `select`.

The subquery returns two records but if it referenced the `a.STRUCT_DOC_id` that was part of the larger query it would only bring in one record.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.STRUCT_DOC_id,
         CASE WHEN Inclusions.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' 
                THEN (SELECT min_value 
                        FROM etIndivCommitt b,
                             mn_structured_contract AA 
                        WHERE b.STRUCT_DOC_id=AA.STRUCT_DOC_id AND
                              b.PP_Sub_Type like '%Wound%')
                ELSE '0'
                END Commitment_Value,
         a.Product_ID
        FROM
            mn_structured_contract a 
            GetIndivCommitt b,
            Inclusions C
        WHERE
            b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
            C.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
```

Comment: `CASE ... ... END` is not a statement, but a *conditional expression*. (compare it to the ternary `a?b:c` in C)

Comment: The error message can't get any clearer.  You inner query is returning more than one row.  Fix it, then the error will disappear.

Comment: AND is missing     between b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
            C.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id

Comment: Which table is `min_value` coming from?

Comment: Maybe `min(value)` rather than `min_value`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to return some `MIN` value of a field for "wound"-related records.  Is that correct?  If so, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    src.STRUCT_DOC_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN src.Wound_Included = 'TRUE' THEN src.MinValueForWoundIncluded
        ELSE '0' 
    END Commitment_Value,
    src.Product_ID
FROM (
    SELECT 
      a.STRUCT_DOC_id,
      a.Product_id,
      C.Wound_Included,
      MIN(
        CASE 
          WHEN PP_Sub_Type LIKE '%wound%' THEN <whatever field you are getting the "min" of> 
          ELSE NULL 
        END) OVER(PARTITION BY a.Struct_DOC_id) AS MinValueForWoundIncluded -- Return the MIN value for each Struct_DOC_id
    FROM mn_structured_contract a, GetIndivCommitt b, Inclusions C
    WHERE b.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id
    AND C.STRUCT_DOC_id=a.STRUCT_DOC_id   
) src
```

A few notes:

- this should work since your joins in the sub-query inside the `CASE` statement are the same as the joins in the outer select (all on `STRUCT_DOC_id`)
- you should replace the `<whatever field you are getting the "min" of>` thing with your actual field
- In your `CASE` statement, where you have `ELSE '0'`...if you want to return a numeric field, you should get rid of the single quotes
- In your original query, you aliased Inclusions table as `C`, but then referred to it again as `Inclusions.Wound_Included` above.  Once you alias a table, you should only reference it by its alias

I haven't tested it, but give it a try and let me know :)